# Import csv file with php

Tags: php, mysql, import, pdo

I'm working with PHP PDO and I have the following error, when I try to upload products in my DB

`Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\wamp64\www\zohir\admin\products.php on line 22`

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// READ UPLOADED CSV
$fh = fopen($_FILES["upcsv"]["tmp_name"], "r");
if ($fh === false) { exit("Failed to open uploaded CSV file"); }

// IMPORT ROW BY ROW
while (($row = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false) {
  try {
    // print_r($row);
    $stmt = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO product(Nom_product,Cat_product,SKU_product,Prix_achat_product,Prix_vente_product,Prix_promo,Stock_product,Statut_product,Date_product,Photo_product,Photo_product_lien,Taille_pointure,Marque_product,Video_product,Desc_product) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,now(),?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->execute([$row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4], $row[5], $row[6], $row[7], $row[8], $row[9], $row[10], $row[11], $row[12], $row[13], $row[14]]);
  } catch (Exception $ex) { echo $ex->getmessage(); }
}
fclose($fh);
}
```

Using this form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="upcsv" accept=".csv"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
                </form>
```

In my DB all entries are text type, only "Date_product" -> datetime, and "Prix_achat_product,Prix_vente_product" -> int
How can I fix that?

I'm trying to add products to my e-com website with a csv file that contain my new products

Comment: You have one too many variables in your execute. You're not binding `now()`, so don't pass anything for that column.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thanks to you "aynber", I just delete the date row and it works.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// READ UPLOADED CSV
$fh = fopen($_FILES["upcsv"]["tmp_name"], "r");
if ($fh === false) { exit("Failed to open uploaded CSV file"); }

// IMPORT ROW BY ROW
while (($row = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false) {
  try {
    // print_r($row);
    $stmt = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO product(Nom_product,Cat_product,SKU_product,Prix_achat_product,Prix_vente_product,Prix_promo,Stock_product,Statut_product,Date_product,Photo_product,Photo_product_lien,Taille_pointure,Marque_product,Video_product,Desc_product) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,now(),?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->execute([$row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4], $row[5], $row[6], $row[7], $row[8], $row[9], $row[10], $row[11], $row[12], $row[13]]);
  } catch (Exception $ex) { echo $ex->getmessage(); }
}
fclose($fh);
}
```